# Spritekit | Swift3 | Assigning a SKSpritenode in the level editor to a SKNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift3, sknode

I have a `SKSpritenode` in the `Level1.sks` called "ballNode". 
This is loaded in the `GameScene` via.

```
ballNode = childNode(withName: "ballNode") as? SKSpriteNode
    ballNode?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: (ballNode?.frame.size.width)! / 2)
    ballNode?.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ballCategory
    ballNode?.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.completeObjectNodeCategory
```

By default the `ballNode` has a parent of the scene. 
How can I add the `ballNode` to a `SKNode` called `_gameNode`?

```
_gameNode = SKNode()
self.addChild(_gameNode)
```

When I try to add the `ballNode` to the `SKnode` via code. It throws a error.

```
_gameNode.addChild(ballNode!)
```

Comment: use moveToParent()

Comment: well that was easy. Thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to KnightOfDragon.
The solution is

```
ballNode?.move(toParent: _gameNode)
```